# Mpdf has a deprecated constructor

Tags: php, codeigniter, mpdf

Quisiera saber cómo solucionar este mensaje de error.
Estoy trabajando con php v. 7.0.22, Codeigniter v. 3.1.0. y Mpdf v. 6.0. Uso SO Lubuntu 17.04. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si vas a trabajar con PHP 7 tienes que actualizar MPDF, en el siguiente enlace encontraras la ultima versión que es compatible con PHP 7 https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/releases, ya que los constructores de clase anteriores no son compatibles.

Comment: Ok, gracias. Descargué el paquete pero las carpetas y archivos son muy diferentes a la versión anterior. Para la versión 6 (estando en Win 7), la descargué de internet y copié la carpeta y sus directorios dentro de mi proyecto codeigniter. Luego en linux, copié el proyecto tal cual lo tenía en windows, y ahí empezaron los problemas. ¿Qué tengo que hacer para actualizar mpdf? No entiendo lo que dice la documentación respecto a composer. Disculpa si son preguntas muy tontas, me estoy inciicando en todo esto. Desde ya, muchas gracias por tu paciencia y colaboración.